# Как сделать неактивную кнопку, когда выбран первый пункт в select option?

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите способ с помощью которого можно запретить нажатие кнопки если всегда выбран пункт (по умолчанию) в select option 'Выбрать сотрудника'. Нашел в интернете самый простой disabled = "disabled" но он не совсем мне подходит.

```
<form method="POST"  name="apple" id="apple" action="index.php" target="_blank">
    <br>
        <br>
            <br>
                <center>
                    <select name="user" id="user">
                        <option >Выбрать сотрудника</option>
                        <? foreach($row as $k=>$val){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?=$val[myid]?>"><?=$val[mname]?></option>
                        <?}?>
                    </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Перейти"/>
                </center>

</form>
```

Comment: А что Вам нужно сделать?

Comment: @Mihanik71, сделать кнопку Перейти неактивной когда выбран пункт Выбрать сотрудника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('select[name=user]').change(function() {
  if ($("#user :selected").val() == 'Выбрать сотрудника') {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="apple" id="apple" action="index.php" target="_blank">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
    <select name="user" id="user">
      <option>Выбрать сотрудника</option>
      <option value="574">adwdawdawdaw</option>
      <option value="574">dawdawdaw</option>
      <option value="574">adwdawda1232313wdaw</option>
      <option value="574">adwda12312312wdawdaw</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Перейти" disabled/>
  </center>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 2 :)

```
<form method="POST"  name="apple" id="apple" action="index.php" target="_blank">
<br>
    <br>
        <br>
            <center>
                <select name="user" id="user">
                    <option selected disabled>Выбрать сотрудника</option>
                    <? foreach($row as $k=>$val){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$val[myid]?>"><?=$val[mname]?></option>
                    <?}?>
                </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Перейти" disabled/>
            </center>
```

JS

```
$('#user').on('change', function() {
 $('#apple input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Естественно надо подключить Jquery

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/Reset5/0jaorqo8/3/

Answer (score 1):

Можно не деактировать кнопку, а воспользоваться аттрибутом `required`.
Тогда при попытке отправить форму сработает валидация:

> Выберите один из пунктов списка

```
<form method="POST">
    <select name="user" id="user" required>
      <option value="">Выбрать сотрудника</option>
      <option value="1">Сотрудник 1</option>
      <option value="2">Сотрудник 2</option>
      <option value="3">Сотрудник 3</option>
      <option value="4">Сотрудник 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Перейти"/>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxmfpk09/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" name="select" id="select" onchange="disable_btn();">
    <option value="0">Выбрать сотрудника</option>
    ....
</select>

<input name="input-name" type="submit" value="Перейти"/>

function disable_btn(){
    if($('select[name=\'select\'] option:selected').val() == 0){
        $('input[name=\'input-id\']').attr("disabled","disabled");
    }else{
        $('input[name=\'input-id\']').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

И ещё проверка состояния селекта при загрузке страницы, если возвращается какой-то option

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    disable_btn();
});
```